# Populating a MySQL db reading a file in a folder

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem. In my FTP server i have a folder with some txt files (abc.txt, hallo.txt, 123.txt ...et cetera), uploaded regularly by a remote software.
These txt files contain data for a MySQL database.

I wonder: how can i populate the MyQSL database automatically (ex. using a cron job)?
I already have a php file able to populate the database, but using a "POST" method (not authomatically). I have to select manually each file to upload and update the database from my computer.

I'd like to setup a php code that reads and picks up the older .txt file, contained in my FTP folder, and provide to update the database.
I already have code able to read inside an .txt file and extrapolate data to insert in the database.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Mat.

Comment: Can you post the relevant php code?

Comment: Cron job what looking for text file in proper folder and execute DB update should be a good solution

Comment: you'll need to store the 'last run time' somewhere. Then you'll need to scan the directory for changed/new files. Then you'll use `LOAD DATA INFILE $myfile ...` to add the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Well, in a few words i'd like to code some lines in php:
1. reads the existing .txt files in the folder
2. picks up the older one
3. "gives" the file to process to another php file wich already populates the database with the files uploaded by post method.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root'); // MAMP defaults 
mysql_select_db('yourdatabase'); 
$files = glob('*.txt'); 
foreach($files as $file){ 
  mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file." INTO yourtablename"); 
}
?>
```

or using a bash script on Linux

```
#!/bin/bash 

for f in *.csv 
do 
      mysql -e "load data infile '"$f"' into table my_table" -u username --password=your_password my_database 
done
```

You can edit crontab to make the script to run on specified intervals.