# Accessing Windows folder in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, windows

I want to access the contents (images) of a folder in my windows 10 in Mysql database and it should access the folder and show its contents

I expect that the output should be like name of the folder is displayed and the image files inside it with file name is displayed in mysql and it gets stored in mysql database after access

Comment: and did you try anything yet?

Comment: It's not possible, MySQL is a database, use a script for it. See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751872/is-it-possible-to-read-list-of-files-using-mysql or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900043/populating-a-mysql-db-reading-a-file-in-a-folder

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in capability of MySQL but it is not impossible. You would need to customize your MySQL server.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-native-function.html